# Newton's way of relating force to geometry

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I am reading Spivak mechanics, while reading the Chapter on Newton's analysis of central force motion, i stumbled upon this limit equation, can you help me with the 'how Mr. Spivak said that displacement here is $(1/2)Fδ²$?'.

[image: The image from the text book, Physics for mathematicias : Mechanics By Michael Spivak]

Comment: I don't understand the diagram, but I suspect that $\tfrac 12 F\delta^2$ is what (for unit mass) we'd write now as $\frac 12 a t^2$, namely the displacement due to an acceleration that is almost constant over a small time interval.

Comment: @PhilipWood i thought so at the first, but you see even if it's unit mass it does have 'unit', by dimensional analysis we are left with M¹L¹, am i missing something?

Comment: It's alright if we replace $F$ by $F/m$, is it not?

Comment: Oh my, yeah it is, but can we do that? Oops, am really rusty here

Comment: @PhilipWood Sir, can you explain that limit to me as well?  How did he ended up with 1/4 there? I am really confused here!

Comment: (a) "but can we do that?" No, we can't do that, but perhaps terminology wasn't as rigid then as it is now. (b) How did he ended up with 1/4 there?" Spivak has explained it in terms of the diagram, but I don't understand where the diagram comes from!

Comment: @PhilipWood (b) The diagram was actually there in the Newton's Principia Preposition 1. It was used to proof the Kepler's Second law.

Comment: I think the figure is an approximation to a curve, and is related to constant areal velocity for a central force. Assuming unit mass and that the velocity is constant during each time interval $\delta$, that I instead denote $\Delta t$ (i.e. between each point A $\rightarrow$ B, and B $\rightarrow$ C), then $F_B\cdot \Delta t =\vec V_{BC}-\vec V_{AB} $, so $F_B\cdot \Delta t^2=(\vec V_{BC}-\vec V_{AB})\Delta t = \vec R_{BC}-R_{AB}=$$BV$ in the figure, so $BB´=\frac{1}{2}BV = \frac{1}{2}F_B\cdot \Delta t^2$. But this differ from the result the author got by a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$...

Comment: @user330563 Thanks a lot! Regarding that other 1/4, the author mentioned that (in the next page) "The  fraction 1/4 doesn't appear in Newton's statement because the result is phrased as a proportion .." So i don't think it's a typing error, can you look into this once more?